# What is the selling price of the lamp?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I'm stuck with the following probability problem:

The lifetime of a lamp in hours was modeled by the random variable $X$ which has the following probability distribution:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
X& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\ \hline 
p_i & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.1
\end{array}$$

Each lamp costs $\$10$ dollars to be manafactured. If the lifespan of the lam is inferior to $6$ hours the vendor will make up for the buyer with a $\$15$ dollars.

What should it be the selling price of each lamp for the vendor go get an average of $\$20$ dollars by lamp?

Can anyone help me?

I assume the problem boils down to expectancy.

Comment: You need to consider the total cost of a lamp, when you know its lifetime. You can start by adding a new row to the table and fillinf in the total cost. Get back to us when you have done that.

Comment: That would be: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}  X& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\ \hline  P & 25  & 10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10\end{array}$$ where $x$ where $P$ is the price of the lamps ($x$ is the number of lamps which have that liefspan).

Comment: I don't think you need to incorporate the number of lamps produced ($x$), we're only looking at single lamps now. Otherwise the table looks good, but reconsider the case with $X=5$. It costs 10 to manufacture the lamp, and in addition, the the buyer will want a 15 dollar compensation. So I would say that in this case, the total cost would be 25 dollars, right?

Comment: Agreed, thanks =)

Comment: Okay, good. Now you have a probability model for the **cost of a single lamp**. Now you need to decide the selling price of the lamp so that the when you take away the cost (which is a random variable), the expected value needs to be 20 dollars.

Comment: The expected cost is: $$E[P]=0.1\cdot 25+0.1\cdot 10+0.2\cdot 10+0.4\cdot 10+0.1\cdot 10+0.1\cdot 10=11.5.$$ In order to get 20 dollars in return the vendor must sell at 31.5?

Comment: @MattiP. Can I see the problem as to find the expectancy of a difference of two random variables?

Comment: So let's review what we know. The cost of a single lamp is a random variable (essentially because we don't know if we have to give the customer another 15 dollars or not). Secondly, the profit is equal to the selling price minus the cost. The selling price is not a random variable. But since the cost is a random variable, the profit is also a random variable. The expected value of the profit is
$$
\mathbb{E}[\text{Profit}] = \mathbb{E}[\text{price} - \text{cost}] = \text{price} - \mathbb{E}[\text{cost}]
$$

Comment: Agreed. Can I also see the cost as a function $f$ of $X$ and use the concept of the expected value of $f(X)$ as $E[f(X)]$?

Comment: yes, exactly like that. Have you finished the calculation?

Comment: Yep, that worked =) Thanks for the help!